# On which site would you ask about jet engines?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I've looked at the Mechanics site and it seems like it's more for cars. However, I have a question about jet engines and there doesn't seem to be a site applicable to general mechanics.

On which site would you ask questions about jet propulsion and aerospace (e.g. rocket and jet engines)?

Comment: I bet we'd love a question about jet engines on [Mech Eng](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/44908/mechanical-engineering?referrer=Ytahv9McMgJquJJw1wTqDg2), if and when it takes off.

Comment: `takes off`, heh...

Comment: I thought it was about [Jet Engines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Jet_Database_Engine) when I saw the title.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you're focused on analysing the rocket as a point projectile with time varying acceleration and mass functions, you might want to try [Physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/). If you're looking at more engineer-ey topics like fuel quantity optimisation or solid mechanics, I recommend you hop aboard the [Aviation & Aerospace](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/42572/aviation-and-aerospace) wagon, or even [Mechanical Engineering](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/44908/mechanical-engineering).

EDIT: The Mechanical Engineering proposal has since sadly been removed, however the Aviation proposal has graduated into a new site which you can check out: https://aviation.stackexchange.com/

Comment: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/43283/space-exploration would also be a good one, when it gets up and running. (It looks like it is getting close, so you may want to commit to the site in order to help it get there!)

Comment: Hoping on the Mech Eng. band wagon.

Comment: FWIW I'd guess that _most_ questions about jet engines would be off topic on [physics.SE], but I couldn't say for sure without seeing the specific question.